# ctree to produce predictions other than the existing categories

Tags: r, classification

I have a ctree to run. In my training set, the response variable has 3 categories: 0, 1, 99.

However, the tree plot produces more value outcomes between 0 and 1:

```
                    Actual
Prediction              0    1   99
  0                  6281    0    0
  0.0869565217391304   63    6    0
  0.288888888888889    32   13    0
  0.529411764705882    24   27    0
  0.588235294117647    35   50    0
  0.625                 9   15    0
  0.641891891891892    53   95    0
  0.684014869888476    85  184    0
  0.807692307692308     5   21    0
  0.853035143769968    46  267    0
  0.864406779661017     8   51    0
  0.892018779342723    23  190    0
  0.896103896103896     8   69    0
  0.95668549905838     23  508    0
  0.98695652173913      3  227    0
  1                     0   58    0
  99                    0    0 3018
```

Does anyone know how is this possible?
Thank you!

Comment: oh, sorry, it is in the R package "party" to produce classification trees

Comment: Did you have the response variable coded as a factor?

Comment: thanks for your remindings! After I do as.factor(response), I get a vector presenting the outcome such as (0.308, 0.692, 0) in plot(tree). Do you know in case how does that work? Thank you!